# OpenLayers: How to add click AND touch event on markers

Tags: javascript, touch, openlayers

I built a map for mobile an browser use so I need a click and tap/touch event for every marker. I've tried adding a click event and then adding a touch event but it works only with one of them.

```
marker.events.register( 'click', marker, function( evt ) {
    $( '#info' ).html(
        '<p>' + data[i].title + '<br />' + data[i].addr + '</p>'
    );
});
//marker.events.register( 'touchstart', marker, function( evt ) {
//  $( '#info' ).html(
//      '<p>' + data[i].title + '<br />' + data[i].addr + '</p>'
//  );
//});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an example on openlayers.org website - [Click Handler Example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/click-handler.html)

You may create a customize control class that extentes OpenLayers.Control, and create a function in the class that use OpenLayers.Handler.Click to listen the click event.

The Handler.Click will actually listen to click event and touch event at the same time.

```
OpenLayers.Control.ListenToClick = OpenLayers.Class(OpenLayers.Control, {
    defaultHandlerOptions: {
        'single': true,
        'pixelTolerance': 0,
        'stopSingle': false
    },

    initialize: function(options) {
        this.handlerOptions = OpenLayers.Util.extend(
            {}, this.defaultHandlerOptions
        );
        OpenLayers.Control.prototype.initialize.apply(
            this, arguments
        ); 
        this.handler = new OpenLayers.Handler.Click(
            this, {
                'click': this.onClick,
            }, this.handlerOptions
        );
    }, 

    onClick: function(evt) {
        $( '#info' ).html(
            '<p>' + data[i].title + '<br />' + data[i].addr + '</p>'
        );
    },
});
```

create it and add to map when you need it

```
var ctmControl = new OpenLayers.Control.ListenToClick({
    handlerOptions: {
        'single': true,
        'pixelTolerance': 0,
        'stopSingle': false
    }
});
map.addControl(ctmControl);
```

If that's not enuough sensitive for you, you may try this

```
'pixelTolerance': 10,
```

Last but not least, remember to activate it

```
ctmControl.activate();
```

You can deactivate it in the same way, of course.

```
ctmControl.deactivate();
```